# Compact space that is not Hausdorff nor locally compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm trying to classify various topological concepts about compactness according to 3 properties: Hausdorff, compactness and locally compactness. Knowing that a Hausdorff and compact space is always locally compact, we can draw this diagram:

```
                  7  +------------------------+
                     |Hausdorff    1          |
                     |      +-----------------+
                     |      |         +-------+------------------+          
                     |      |    2    |   3   |           compact|
                     |      |         |       |      4           |
                     +------+---------+-------+                  |
                            |    5    |   6   |                  |
                            |         +-------+------------------+
                            |locally compact  |        
                            +-----------------+
```

I would like to find examples for each number of the diagram above.
Until now I have the following ones:

1. Hausdorff space that is not compact nor locally compact: $\mathbb{Q}$ (endowed with the topology from $\mathbb{R}$) (edit)
2. Hausdorff and locally compact space that is not compact: $\mathbb{R^n}$
3. Hausdorff and compact space (therefore locally compact): ${[0,1]}$ (endowed with the topology from $\mathbb{R}$)
4. Compact space that is not Hausdorff nor locally compact:
5. Locally compact space that is not Hausdorff nor compact: $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with the topology compound by the usual $\mathbb{R}$ open sets that contain $\lbrace0 \rbrace$
6. Compact and locally compact space that is not Hausdorff: ${\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace}$ endowed with Sierpinski's topology
7. Space that is not Hausdorff nor compact and nor locally compact:

I am having problems to find examples for 1, 4 and 7.

Note: The definition of locally compact space might vary depending on the author. I am considering that a space is locally compact if every point has a local base of compact neighborhoods (without any other extra condition).

Comment: Can't you use $\mathbb Q$ for (1)?

Comment: Have you consulted the book "Counterexamples in Topology"?

Comment: Any finite topological space is trivially compact...

Comment: For non-Hausdorff topological spaces the term "locally compact" is not well defined and there are numerous non-equivalent definitions. See wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space Which defintion you use?

Comment: $\alpha \Bbb Q$ will do for 4.

Comment: For 7 the product space $\Bbb Q \times \{0,1\}$ will do, where $\{0,1\}$ is indiscrete.

Comment: You should give us your definition of "locally compact". For general spaces there are various alternative versions.

Comment: For those asking for my definition of "locally compact" it is at the end of the question.

Comment: @pepe Compact space are locally compact always!!!!

Comment: @aliakbar if your definition of locally compact is that every point has a compact neighborhood the you are right as you can take the the whole set as a compact neighborhood of every point. However this is not valid for the definition of locally compact that I use. Please check the note at the end of the question.